# Is it possible to run VACUUM FULL in Postgres asynchronously?

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I am working on some unused data purging scripts on `Postgres 9.1`.  `VACUUM FULL` is necessary to reclaim physical space after purging.  However, with my data volume (5M+ rows), it takes several minutes to execute it.  Since the vacuum needs to be incorporated in the script, I was wondering if it is possible to kick it off asynchronously (or schedule it) so that my script can just finish without waiting?

Comment: Is there any reason why you have turned of normal autovaccum? This should address this in background. Also how do you delete the lines?

Comment: I never turned it off.  How do I check the value of that setting on the server?

Comment: If you never turned it off, it should be running in background -- so unless you are really at some very special case, you don't need to trigger it manually. Check documentation for more details. It's really a huge, but interessting topic.

Answer (score 3):

### Do you need `VACUUM FULL`?

> `VACUUM FULL` is necessary to reclaim physical space after purging

Yes, if you want to return that space to the OS or use it in other tables.

If you expect to just re-use the space for new rows in the same table, you're better off just running normal `VACUUM` (or letting autovaccum do its job), so the blocks containing deleted rows are marked as free for re-use. Shrinking and growing tables is a heavyweight operation that's best avoided if you're just going to re-use the space.

### `VACUUM FULL` without locks

Pg doesn't provide a `VACUUM FULL CONCURRENTLY`.

There's a client-based effort to do the equivalent, [called `pg_repack`](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack). I can't speak for its safety/reliability.

In general we tend to avoid `VACUUM FULL` in favour of just letting normal `VACUUM` clear space for re-use within the table.